# Questions about a hypergeometric random variable with sums of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'm studying probability with Ross's textbook.
In 4.9 EXPECTED VALUE OF SUMS OF RANDOM VARIABLES, the textbook says that

> We can interpret the hypergeometric as representing the number
>   of successes in $n$ trials, where trial $i$ is said to be a success if the $i$th ball selected is white. Because the $i$th ball selected is equally likely to be any of the $N$ balls and thus has probability $m/N$ of being white, it follows that the hypergeometric is the number of successes in $n$ trials in which each trial is a success with probability $p = m/N$. Hence, even though these hypergeometric trials are dependent, it follows from the result of Example 9d that the expected value of the hypergeometric is $np = nm/N$.

But I'm wondering why the ith ball selected is equally likely to be any of the N balls. Because I'm not a native speaker, I'm confused what does ith ball selected means exactly and why it becomes equally likely in spite of the fact that trials are dependent.

Thanks for everyone, in advance.

Comment: You draw the balls in order without replacement.  You could imagine this as drawing all $N$ balls in one of $N!$ equally likely orders and looking at the first $n$ of them.  The $i$th draw (i.e. the $i$th ball in order) could be any of the $N$ balls and each is equally likely.

Comment: Closely related: [If you draw two cards, what is the probability the second card is a Queen?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287393/if-you-draw-two-cards-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-card-is-a-queen)

Comment: @Henry Thanks for  answering.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, this article is really helpful.