# Is drawing straws fair if there are 2 short straws instead of the customary 1?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that the probability is fair for the normal version (i.e. you stop drawing after the only short straw is drawn.) But what if there are 2 short straws? Wouldn't the odds change after the first is drawn?

Comment: It may help to describe the "normal version" explicitly (how many people? how many straws? what is the goal?) for context.

Comment: Say the normal version was 1 short straw, 3 long straws, 4 people. My question is, would the math hold true for 2 short straws, 2 long straws, 4 people, after the first of 2 short straws had been drawn?

Comment: If the order of the people drawing is fixed, then the two scenarios are entirely different: in the second scenario, it is impossible for the 4th person to "lose" (get a short straw).

Comment: What do you mean by "does the math hold true"?  I still don't understand what question you are asking.

Comment: With four straws, two of which short, and all straws drawn, each of the possible pairs of people of the four are equally likely to have received a short straw and each of the four people have a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of having drawn a short straw.  Now... *given that the first short straw was drawn by the first person* then each of the three remaining people have an equally likely chance of drawing the remaining short straw.  So, in that sense "*after the first is drawn*" yes, the odds change *given that information*... but it isn't clear if this was what you were after.

Comment: This sounds a lot like [If you draw two cards, what is the probability the second card is a queen?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287393/if-you-draw-two-cards-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-card-is-a-queen)... that you are concerned about how a first draw impacts future draws.

Comment: Is it that the first person to draw the short straw loses, and everyone else wins?

Comment: Now... if, as your comments suggest, you just draw until *any* short straw is drawn and stop drawing... then as pointed out after three straws are drawn at least one of them is guaranteed to have been a short straw (*by pigeonhole principle*), so a fourth person in line will not have had an opportunity to have drawn.