# Turning over blue and pink cups until the gender of the baby is known.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to do the following problem, and want to know why my approach does not work.

> A “gender reveal” party is held to announce the gender of an expected newborn. 15 cups are filled in advance with colored beads and covered: if the baby is a boy, 8 are filled with blue beads and 7 with pink. If the baby is a girl, 7 are filled with blue and 8 with pink. When the audience arrives the cups are knocked over (revealing bead colors) in a uniformly random order until the audience has seen 8 cups of the same color (and thereby knows the gender). Let N be the number of cups turned over before the gender is known. Compute the probability that N = k for k ∈ {8, 9, 10, . . . , 15}. Is the probability that N = 15 (and one has to wait to the very end) more or less than 1/2?

Let $E_i$ be the event that the gender of the baby is known after the $i^{\text{th}}$ cup is turned over, for $i \in \{ 8,9,10,...,15 \}$. Let Boy be the event that the baby is a boy, and Girl the event that it is a girl. Then the desired probability is:
$$P(E_i) = P(E_i| \text{Boy})P(\text{Boy}) + P(E_i| \text{Girl})P(\text{Girl}) $$

For a particular $i$, we try to compute $P(E_i| \text{Boy})$. Given that the baby is a boy, there would be 8 cups filled with blue beads and 7 cups filled with pink beads. If we place the cups in a line, then the outcomes we are interested in, i.e., the ones where we have to turn over the $i^{\text{th}}$ cup (from left to right) before the gender of the baby is known, are the cases where the $i^{\text{th}}$ cup is a cup filed with blue beads (denoted $B$), and all the cups to the right of it are filled with pink beads (denoted $P$), i.e., the situation in the following diagram:

$${\underbrace{\_ \phantom{.} \_ \phantom{.} \_ \dots \underline{B} }_\text{i}} \phantom{.} {\underbrace{\underline{P} \phantom{.} \underline{P} \phantom{.} \underline{P} \dots \underline{P} } _\text{15-i}}$$

In the above diagram, there are $7 \choose {15-i}$ ways to choose the rightmost pink-beads cups, with $(15-i)!$ ways to permute each selection, 8 ways to choose the blue-beads cup at position $i$, and $(i-1)!$ ways to arrange the remaining cups. So we'd have:

$$P(E_i| \text{Boy}) = \frac{{7 \choose {15-i}} \cdot (15-i)! \cdot 8 \cdot (i-1)!}{15!}$$

Given that the situation is similar when the baby is a girl, and that $P(\text{Boy}) = P(\text{Girl}) = \frac{1}{2}$, we'd have:
$$P(E_i) = \frac{{7 \choose {15-i}} \cdot (15-i)! \cdot 8 \cdot (i-1)!}{15!}$$

But this is wrong, since, with $i = 15$, for example, we'd have $P(E_{15}) \approx 3.73$. Where did I go wrong with my analysis?

Comment: Well, for one thing, we don't have $P(E_i) = 2P(E_i|\text{Boy})$, we have $P(E_i) = P(E_i|\text{Boy})$. So the 8 in the numerator should not have changed into 16. But this doesn't really help you get a reasonable answer.

Comment: The probability you need all 15 is simply going to be the probability the final revealed is the dominant color.  This is the same as the probability the first revealed is the dominant color.  That will occur with probability $\dfrac{8}{15}$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287393/if-you-draw-two-cards-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-card-is-a-queen

Comment: @Arthur you are right! I fixed that bit.

Comment: With regards to your arithmetic error... it would appear you had an extra factor of $7$ somehow, as $7\times \frac{8}{15}\approx 3.73$.  Perhaps you did $\binom{7}{16-i}$ instead accidentally?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't see an issue with your analysis, and when I calculate $P(E_{15})$ according to your formula, I get
$$
\frac{\binom 70 \cdot 0!\cdot 8\cdot 14!}{15!} = \frac{1\cdot 1\cdot 8\cdot 14!}{14!\cdot 15} = \frac 8{15}
$$

---

However, there is a *much* faster way to do this.

The gender is known before the last cup if the last cup contains a bead of the color there are 7 of, and it will still be unknown after flipping 14 cups if the final cup contains a bead of the color there are 8 of. The probability that it contains an 8-bead is $\frac{8}{15}>\frac12$.