# Understanding selecting without replacement when a previous selection does not matter

Tags: probability

This is likely a question with answers everywhere, but I am unsure how to phrase it so I find answers.

Lets say you have $100$ hammers where $23$ are defective.

**Example 1**: If you select two, one at a time, without replacement, what is the probability the second one is defective?

**A1**: The way I would naturally answer it is:

$\frac{23}{100}\times\frac{22}{99}+\frac{77}{100}\times\frac{23}{99} = \frac{23}{100}$.

This is the same probability that the first hammer chosen being defective.

**Example 2**: If you select $3$, one at a time, without replacement, what is the probability the first is defective but the last is not?

**A1**: Once again the way I would naturally answer it is:

$\frac{23}{100}\times\frac{22}{99}\times\frac{77}{98}+\frac{23}{100}\times\frac{77}{99}\times\frac{76}{98} = \frac{161}{900} = \frac{23}{100}\times\frac{77}{99}$.

This is the same probability that the first hammer chosen is defective, and the second not.

What I am getting at is the probabilites were the same when ignoring the "does not matter" choice. Assuming I am not mistaking something, how does this make sense? I can't seem to wrap my head around it intuitively or mathmatically. I would expect that because it is without replacement, even a "does not matter" changes the probability by reducing the total hammer count.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189383/139123 ... Does that help?

Comment: @DavidK actually it does thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered in comments by David K

[A probability interview questions on pen type](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189349/a-probability-interview-questions-on-pen-type/1189383#1189383)

related to not having information on the unknown makes no changes to the probability