Game of Pigeons - Probability Puzzle
The Problem:
Alice and Bob take turns drawing a pigeon from a sack which initially contains $W$ white and $B$ black pigeons. The first person to draw a white pigeon wins. After each pigeon drawn by Bob the rest of pigeons in the bag panic, and one of them flies out of the sack itself but Alice draws her pigeon carefully and doesn't scare the other pigeons. Alice draws first. What is the probability of Alice winning?
Clarifications:

If there are no more pigeons in the sack and nobody has drawn a white pigeon, Bob wins. Pigeons which fly out of the sack themselves are not considered to be drawn (does not define the winner).
Every pigeon is drawn from the sack with the same probability as every other one, and every pigeon flies out of the bag with the same probability as every other one.
Once a pigeon has left the sack, it never returns to it.

Example: If $W=1, B=3$, then $P($Alice winning$) = 0.5$
My Approach: I tried formulating a $2D$ recursion. I am having trouble including the randomness of the aftermath of every draw made by Bob. Had it been the case that the draw of Bob was identical to that of Alice (i.e. Bob doesn't scare of one random pigeon in every draw), I would have been able to solve it using the recursion.
How do I formulate the recursion? Is there a different approach that is more appropriate?

This is the same game as three players alternating drawing pigeons, except that the game doesn't stop if C draws a white pigeon. Does that help with the recursive setup?

Wouldn't I have to make a $3D$ recursion then? Also I dont understand how to include whose turn it is in the recursion. Is that even required?

Look at Markov's chain.

@Lourrran I'm familiar with the concept. Can you elaborate on it in the present context?

Sorry, bad suggestion, Markov is useful mainly for processes which can be infinite.

@BrianTung Please read the question carefully. The first clarification point addresses exactly what you asked. In my example, $P$(Bob wins) $=\frac12$

Ahh, OK. Obviously, none of this affects the probability Alice wins, but thanks for the clarification.

Alice wins with probability one. She just looks into the sack on her first turn, and picks out a white pigeon. Well, that was easy!

Let $P(W,B)$ the conditional probability if it is Alice's turn and the bag currently contains $W \geq 0$ white pigeons and $B \geq 0$ black pigeons that Bob will win. (The formulas and numbers for Bob winning turn out to be a little simpler than for Alice winning.) It's helpful to write the recurrence relation in terms of times when it's Alice's turn.
For the easiest cases, we have $P(0,B)=1$ for any $B$, and $P(W,0)=0$ if $W>0$.
If $B=1$, then Alice wins this turn with probability $\frac{W}{W+1}$. Or with probability $\frac{1}{W+1}$, there are now no black pigeons in the bag, so Bob will win. Therefore $$P(W,1)=\frac{1}{W+1}$$
If $B=2$ and $W \geq 1$, then Alice wins this turn with probability $\frac{W}{W+2}$. Or with probability $\frac{2}{W+2}$, Alice gets a black pigeon and there is just one black pigeon in the bag. Conditional on that, Bob gets a turn. Either Bob gets a white pigeon and wins with probability $\frac{W}{W+1}$, or Bob gets the last black pigeon and loses with probability $\frac{1}{W+1}$. Therefore
$$ P(W,2)=\frac{2}{W+2} \cdot \frac{W}{W+1} = \frac{2W}{(W+1)(W+2)} $$
In the remaining cases, $W \geq 1$ and $B \geq 3$. First Alice draws one pigeon, winning with probability $\frac{W}{W+B}$. Or with probability $\frac{B}{W+B}$, there are now $W$ white pigeons and $B-1$ black pigeons in the bag, and it's Bob's turn.
If Bob gets a turn, Bob wins with probability $\frac{W}{W+B-1}$. Or with probability $\frac{B-1}{W+B-1}$, there are now $W$ white pigeons and $B-2$ black pigeons in the bag, before any more fly out.
If neither player won this turn, a random pigeon flies away. With probability $\frac{W}{W+B-2}$, a white pigeon escapes and there are now $W-1$ pigeons and $B-2$ black pigeons in the bag. Or with probability $\frac{B-2}{W+B-2}$, a black pigeon escapes and there are now $W$ white pigeons and $B-3$ black pigeons in the bag. Therefore with $W \geq 1$ and $B \geq 3$,
$$ P(W,B) = \frac{B}{W+B} \left(\frac{W}{W+B-1} + \frac{B-1}{W+B-1}\left(\frac{W P(W-1,B-2) + (B-2)P(W,B-3)}{W+B-2}\right)\right) $$
$$ P(W,B) = \frac{WB(W+B-2) + WB(B-1) P(W-1,B-2) + B(B-1)(B-2) P(W,B-3)}{(W+B)(W+B-1)(W+B-2)} $$
That fully defines the recursion. Now to see if there are helpful patterns, we can start drawing the triangle of values. The $n$-th row (counting from zero) will contain the values with $W+B=n$, starting with $W=0, B=n$ and ending with $W=n, B=0$. It's a little like Pascal's triangle, but not so simple to recursively compute.
$$ \begin{array}{cccccc}
1 \\
1 & 0 \\
1 & \frac 12 & 0 \\
1 & \frac 13 & \frac 13 & 0 \\
1 & \frac 12 & \frac 13 & \frac 14     & 0 \\
1 & \frac 35 & \frac 25 & \frac{3}{10} & \frac 15     & 0 \\
1 & \frac 23 & \frac 25 & \frac{7}{20} & \frac{4}{15} & \frac 16 & 0
\end{array} $$
Of course, the probability Alice wins is $1 - P(W,B)$.
There may be a closed form for $P(W,B)$, but it's not obvious.

Suppose that Alice and Bob continue to take pigeons from the bag until the bag is empty, but we still consider the first one who draws a white pigeon to be the winner, or if nobody draws a white pigeon, Bob wins.
If there were originally $w$ white pigeons and $b$ black pigeons in the sack, this results in a sequence of $w+b$ events: Alice draws, Bob draws, pigeon escapes, repeat until all pigeons are gone.
Any sequence of $w$ white pigeons and $b$ black pigeons is equally likely.
There are $\dbinom{w+b}b$ such sequences if we distinguish the pigeons only by their color.
We can change the order is which we list the events so that all the escapes come last. All sequences of pigeons remain equally likely.
This shows that we get the same results if there are no escapes (instead, Alice and Bob simply draw pigeons alternately) but we end the game when the number of pigeons remaining is no greater than the number already drawn by Bob.
So there actually is nothing to stop you from doing the recursion the simple way. You just need to ensure that the recursion stops before Alice draws too many pigeons.

I disagree. Why do you say we can change the order in which we list the events so that all escapes come last?

@Crostul The entire answer is a multi-step explanation about why we can list the events is a different order from the order in which they occur. If you have a question about a specific step in the reasoning please ask. Of course this does not work if Alice might change her strategy after seeing a pigeon escape, or if the problem asked for a probability conditioned on the color of an escaped pigeon. But sometimes it is possible to determine that certain events can be ignored in a calculation. For example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189383/139123

@Crostul - I assume you do not object to the game continuing until the bag is empty.  Suppose you and I are both recording the game, and each pigeon has a different name - Cedric, David, Elaine, Fanny, etc.  You record in this format: alice1=Wyatt, bob1=Peter, flyaway1=Elaine, alice2=Fanny, bob2=Sam, flyaway2=Manny...  I record in this format: alice1=Wyatt, bob1=Peter, alice2=Fanny, bob2=Sam, ..., flyaway1=Elaine, flyaway2=Manny...  We each end up with an n-long array of these n distinct names.

[cont'd] Our arrays are different, because our recording formats are different, but they represent the same game, with the same result.  Now consider that every such array (out of $n!$ possibilities) is equally likely.  David's answer is saying that it is easier to calculate the required probability if we use my recording format, not yours.  Does this help?
