Probability of drawing a red ball from Box B
There are two boxes, A and B. Box A has 3 white balls and 4 red balls, and Box B has 1 red ball. A fair die is rolled once. If the die rolls an even number, a random ball is drawn from box A and put into box B, and if the die rolls an odd number, 2 balls are drawn at random from box A and put into box B. After this process, a ball is drawn from box B, what is the probability that it is a red ball?

My attempt :-
Case 1: when the die outcome is even
Case 1a) Box A = 2 white, 4 red and Box B= 1 white, 1 red
$\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$
Case 1b) Box A = 3 white, 3 red and Box B= 0 white, 2 red
$\frac{1}{2}*1$
Case 2: when the die outcome is odd
Case 2a) Box A = 1 white, 4 red and Box B= 2 white, 1 red
$\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{3}$
Case 2b) Box A = 2 white, 3 red and Box B= 1 white, 2 red
$\frac{1}{2}*\frac{2}{3}$
Case 2c) Box A = 3 white, 2 red and Box B= 0 white, 3 red
$\frac{1}{2}*1$
The $\frac{1}{2}$ probability in each case represents the probability of even/odd number on the die and the second probability being multiplied is the probability of red ball in box 2
All are probabilites are adding to more than 1 which shouldn't be the case.  The official answer is $\frac{3}{4}$.  Please let me know the flaw in my logic

To start with, I don't see the probabilities of drawing white or red balls  from box A coming into the equations at all.

Please take a careful look at the text of the solution-verification tag. A question with that tag must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

There are some flaws in your attempt . I shall explain in detail for one case:
$\underline{\mathtt{Die \;roll\;is\;even}}$

For the case where the die roll is even ($Pr = \frac12$), there is a probability of $\frac37$ that we add a white ball to box $2$ , and a probability of $\frac47$ that we add a red ball

So P(red ball drawn from box 2)$= \frac12\left(\frac37\frac12 + \frac47\frac22\right) = \frac{11}{28}$


$\underline{\mathtt{Die\;roll\; is\; odd}}$

You need to proceed similarly for the case when the die roll is odd. This will be a bit more complex as you would be drawing and transferring two balls from box $1$ You can now try with the hint given for even roll.

$\underline{\mathtt{Add\; to\; get\; answer}}$

Finally, add the two figures obtained to get the answer


Hello, can you please try and answering my recently asked question titled "Game of Pigeons" :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4909777/game-of-pigeons-probability-puzzle

You're close, but take the case when you roll an even number. Indeed this happens $\frac{1}{2}$ the time. You then draw a ball from box $A$. $\frac{3}{7}$ of the time the ball is white and $\frac{4}{7}$ of the time it is red. Therefore, the probability that you roll an even and draw a white from $A$ and and draw a red from $B$ is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{28}$$
